# How to make a file attribute immutable?

Tags: files, arch-linux

I have a cron file that automatically shutdowns the pc and a pam file that prevents to log in after midnight. The goal is to make both of this files immutables, one way to do this is using `sudo chattr +i file`, what i am looking is a way of making the immutable attribute imposible to remove even for root (`sudo chattr -i file`). Is this possible?

Comment: Do you run SELinux? If not, then root always has the ability change everything.

Comment: No, i have never heard about it, i will research it.

Comment: If this is to keep your kids from staying up on the computer too late, then perhaps try changing the root password and reduce the permissions granted by `sudo`.